# Переключить язык сайта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть вот такой код. Нужно что бы задавался дэфолтный язык, и на этом языке выводилось сообщение алертом **Ваш язык RU |или| ENG**. А также выводилось сообщение на выбранном языке которое берётся из спана. Спаны в сss прячутся.

```css
.lang {
  display: none;
}

.lang.visible {
  display: inline;
  visibility: hidden;
  font: 1em sans-serif;
}
```

```html
 <div id="languages">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="lang">RU
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="lang">ENG
    </label>
  </div>

  <div id="welcome-message">
    <span class="lang lang-ru">Привет</span>
    <span class="lang lang-eng">Hello</span>
    , username!

    <span class="lang lang-ru">Рады тебя видеть!</span>
  </div>

  <button id="save">Save</button>
```

вот код который я думаю можно будет использовать:

```js
var applyLanguage = function (lang) {
 alert('now language is: ' + lang);
}

var getCurrentLanguage = function () {
 var defaultLanguage = 'ru';
 //
  
  return defaultLanguage;
}

var currentLang = getCurrentLanguage();
var langEls = document.getElementsByClassName('lang-' + currentLang);

for (var i=0; i<langEls.length; i++) {
 var langEl = langEls[i];
 
  // langEl.style.display = 'inline';
  langEl.classList.add('visible');
}





// $<prefix> == DOMElement
var $save = document.querySelector('html body button#save')

$save.addEventListener('click', function(){
 alert(1);
});
```

только вот дальше как я чет не знаю

Comment: это может реализоваться многими способами .. к примеру если сайт статичный то создаётся json файл и уже на js вытягиваем по клику нужный json или просто несколько страниц с русским текстами и с английским ... и при клике на eng ru просто переходим по ссылкам , а вот если динамический сайт ... хм

Comment: если же сайт динамичный то в базе храним два вида текста и выводим по требованию/запросу нужный .. для wordpress есть масса плагинов-переводчиков ...

Comment: это не то чтобы сайт, это я для себя пробую, кинул код который я думаю реализовать

Comment: а ну тогда просто ... сделай к примеру две страницы .. одна на ru другая на en и внутри ссылки обычные с одной на другую ...